# woocommerce display features products by category id

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i want to display features products by category id

i found code but it display all features products

this is the code:

```
<?php
    $meta_query  = WC()->query->get_meta_query();
    $tax_query   = WC()->query->get_tax_query();
    
    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
        'field'    => 'name',
        'terms'    => 'featured',
        'operator' => 'IN',
    );

    $args = array(
         'meta_query'          => $meta_query,
        'tax_query'           => $tax_query,
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        endwhile;
?>
```

but i want to make it display features products by category id

Answer (score 0):

I found the code .. thanks

```
<?php
$meta_query  = WC()->query->get_meta_query();
$tax_query   = WC()->query->get_tax_query();
$args = array(
'post_type'             => 'product',
'post_status'           => 'publish',
'posts_per_page'        => '12',
'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
     array(
       'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
       'field' => 'term_id',
       'terms' => 16,
        'operator'      => 'IN'
     ),
     array(
       'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
       'field' => 'name',
       'terms' => 'featured',
         'operator' => 'IN',
     )
    )
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
    endwhile;
```

?>